# Use a variable inside an html quote

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using angular and i have this HTML code

```
      <input
      onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==12 && event.keyCode!=8) return false;"/>
```

How can i add the variable "myNum" instead of that 12?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have defined mynum in your .js file?

```
<input
  onKeyDown="if(this.value.length=={{mynum}} && event.keyCode!=8) return false;"/>
```

though that is very unclean like this.

you would better write a method that you call here:

```
<input onKeyDown=checkInput(this.value.length, event.keyCode)>
```

and in your .js in the method you can make the check and return true/false:

```
checkInput(int valueLength, int keyCode){
   if (valueLength == this.mynum && keyCode != 8){
     return false;
   }
}
```